# How does " into" work on proc sql?

Tags: sas

This is PROC SQL. Could anyone explain what I am getting as output ? Thanks !

```
proc sql;
select time into :date from end_date;
quit;
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Chris J's answer, the `INTO` clause has a very versatile functionality. The following resources will give you very good overview.

Essentially using the `INTO` clause you can create a macro variable which holds a lists of items seperated by a custom delimiter, create a whole host of macro variables inside a single `PROC SQL` procedure - a task which could take multiple `DATA _NULL_` steps & `PROC SORT\MEANS\FREQ` steps etc...

It is the `PROC SQL` equivalent of using `%let date = <some time value>;` or inside a datastep

```
DATA _NULL_;
set end_date;
call symputx("date", time);
RUN;
```

[Using the Magical Keyword "INTO:" in PROC SQL](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi27/p071-27.pdf)

[SAS(R) 9.2 Macro Language: Reference: INTO Clause](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000543554.htm)

Answer (score 1):

It simply puts the result into a macro variable, in this case the macro variable 'DATE' contains the time value off the record in the dataset end_date.

Comment: In addition, it also prints the value of `time` variable to either standard SAS Report of HTML output (depending on your settings). You can suppress that behaviour by using the `NOPRINT` option as in `proc sql noprint;`